# Filter an array using conditions stored in another array

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
const parks = [
    {
        "properties": {
            "name": "Park 1",
            "parking": "",
            "type": "park",
            "picnic_area": 1
        },
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "name": "Park 2",
            "parking": 1,
            "type": "park",
            "picnic_area": ""
        },
    }
];
```

The page have a list of checkboxes. When user check/uncheck one of then, a function generate an object with all the selected checkboxes:

```
{
    "parking": true,
    "picnic_area": true
}
```

My question is: how can I use this object to generate the conditions inside a `filter()` function? Something like:

```
const parksData = parks.filter(object => {
    return object_condition_1 && object_condition_2;
});
```

Comment: Can you have `false` values in the filter object, like `parkings: false`? Or other values that need to be matched explicitly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, you need to rename keys in the filters object so that they match properties' keys, that is, `parking`, not `parkings`. Then,

```
result = parks.filter(p =>
    Object.keys(filters).every(key => 
        Boolean(p.properties[key]) === Boolean(filters[key]))
)
```

This implements an AND condition, that is, only return objects that match all filters. If you need OR instead, replace `every` with `some`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const parks = [
    {
        "properties": {
            "name": "Park 1",
            "parking": "",
            "type": "park",
            "picnic_area": 1
        },
    },
    {
        "properties": {
            "name": "Park 2",
            "parking": 1,
            "type": "park",
            "picnic_area": ""
        },
    }
];

const filter = {
    "parkings": false,
    "picnic_areas": true
};

console.log(parks.filter(park => (filter.parkings && !!park.properties.parking) || (filter.picnic_areas && !!park.properties.picnic_area)));
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is: I need a more dynamic approach because the real scenario can have multiples checkboxes/conditions.